# Full-Text Search for category with all parents in a row

Tags: search, parent, categories, full-text-search

Full-Text Search for category with all parents in a row:
CatLevel1 >> CatL2 >> CatLn >> SearchedCategory

I've got 4 columns in my category table: CatID, CatName, CatDepth, ParentID
Some categories got a 3 level depth and some other 7. 
I want to have the target category with all its parents in one row.

Let me explain by an example:

Searched Keyword: metal
Search Result:
1: Finished Machinery > Machine Tools, Wood & Metalworking Machinery > Metal Processing Machinery > Metal Bending Machinery
2: Non-Metallic Minerals > Other Products > Metal Processing Machinery > Metal Bending Machinery
3: Non-Metallic Minerals > Other Products > Metal Processing Machinery > Metal Casting Machinery
...

I tried many ways to write a flexible query, but none of them work as I wish.
Any kind help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks Kardo

[ekardo]-[at]-[gmail]-[dot]-[com]

Answer (score 0):

If this is a hierarchic Bill of Materials, then you could use

```
CONNECT BY
```

to return the hierarchy (in Oracle)

Comment: Hi Randy,
Yeah, it's hierarchy (self-join) in SQL Server and I'll use it as a Stored Procedure for C# ASP.NET web application.
I'll be really thankful if you provide the whole query. I'm really confused what else to do.
Thanks for your attention.
Kardo

Comment: here seems to be a good discussion of the issue for sql server...
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/more-trees-hierarchies-in-sql